# saving backup on another server

Tags: php, mysql, ftp, backup, fopen

I have a script that takes backup of my db at server1,and saves in a file `[Date].sql`.To be on safe side I want that I want to save the same file on another server as well. I have access to both server. `fopen, fwrite ,fclose` is not helpful here anymore what should I do now?

Comment: ftp? ssh? print out the backups then OCR it back in on the other machine? You've got tons of options available.

Comment: @MarcB I am familir with ftp only.. is there any command available?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php